# This bounty that I shouldn't have won

Tags: discussion, bounty

There was a bounty on this question : [Is it possible to deploy a Qt Quick application without Qt Network on OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30752815/2307070) which I [won](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30801938/2307070) because the bounty expired. I won 25 rep [which is nice](https://imgflip.com/i/n5z9x). But reading the doc I saw:

> If you do not award the bounty within 24 hours of the bounty period ending, half the bounty value will be automatically awarded to the top voted answer posted after the bounty start, provided it has a score of at least 2. If no new answer matches this requirement, no reputation will be awarded at all, and the reputation used on the bounty will be lost forever.

But I'm not the best answerer, the best one has +1 vote up and his answer has been accepted. How is it possible that I won that bounty?

---

A bit out of topic, I read this also in the help page:

> Please note that once a bounty is started, the reputation is non-refundable under any circumstances.

Which is [false](https://stackoverflow.com/users/810312/grigor-gevorgyan?tab=reputation) <sup>(see 2 days ago and the 11th of June)</sup> but that's not important.

Comment: The accepted answer is a self answer. You can't award a bounty to yourself.

Comment: @MartinSmith Ok that's why I didn't check for the author, that seemed so weird to answer your own bounty. Anyway, your comment look like an answer to me.

Comment: No it's a comment. As an answer it would be decidedly anaemic.

Comment: On the caveat to *"non-refundable"*, note that moderators can now manually refund bounties (e.g. to allow closure/migration - see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/27103/248731), but I guess that functionality shouldn't be too widely advertised!

Comment: @MartinSmith well, what else there is to say about it? sounds like answer to me.

Answer (score -4):

If a bounty timeouts, and there is at least one answer with at least +2, then the highest scoring one will get the half of the bounty. If there are multiple highest scoring ones, then the first posted will win.

It is decided based on the scores in the moment of the timeout. Later the scoring can change by newer votes.

On the rules, you are the winner of the bounty and so is it. The bounty opener shouldn't have let to expire his bounty, or the voters should have been faster.

About the non-important part: mods can refund bounties, but it requires a strong reason ("sorry I clicked falsely" is probably not an enough strong one).

Comment: Note: The answer must be added after the start of the bounty in order to be eligible for the automatic award of 1/2 the bounty amount.